# Kotlin. How to implement internal interface in open class?

Tags: kotlin

I want an open class to implement internal interface and use this interface only within the package. If I make this internal interface non-internal, it requires me to make non-internal all the classes used in this interface and then it creates a domino of changes, so I need to make everything non-internal

something like:

```
open class Form : Interface {
  override fun a(): ActionExecutor {}
}

internal interface Interface {
  fun a(): ActionExecutor
}
```

When I try to compile it I get the following error
`Form.kt: (74, 16): 'public' function exposes its 'internal' return type ActionExecutor`

Comment: Are there any errors when you try to implement internal interface?

Comment: Yeah, added to derscription

Comment: It's bcz `ActionExecutor` class is internal. Can you make it not internal?

Answer (score 2):

When an interface is marked with [`internal`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) modifier any client inside this [module](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#modules) who sees the declaring class sees its internal members. If you want to use an entity with `internal` modifier in another module you must remove this modifier. That can lead to chain removes because that entity may use other `internal` entities.

When you implement `internal` interface using `public` class you are exposing its `internal` members, which is prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to compile it I get the following error Form.kt: (74, 16): 'public' function exposes its 'internal' return type ActionExecutor

Then `fun a(): ActionExecutor` already can't be public in `Form`, regardless of implementing `Interface`. Because if it were, users outside the module could call it and get an `ActionExecutor`, which they shouldn't be able to.

One option is not to implement the interface directly on `Form`, but to make a method/property returning it:

```
open class Form {
    // some methods
    internal val asInterface: Interface = object : Interface {
        override fun a(): ActionExecutor {
            // can access members of Form here
        }
    }
}
```

Then code in the same module is free to see a `Form` as an `Interface`, and outside code can't, so there is no problem.